# How do I generate a list of packages added since installation

Tags: package-management, customization

A number of useful pages show how to generate a list of all installed packages, eg
[How do I generate a package download list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168352/how-do-i-generate-a-package-download-list)

Is there a way to restrict the generated list to those I have added *since* system installation?

That is, excluding all the packages that were installed from the ISO? and excluding any updates to *those* packages? Diffing the list generated from the link above with the ISO manifest doesn't quite work because some of the packages in the manifest (eg drivers) are dependent on the hardware and the user selections at install time (eg language).

What I'm looking for is a list of what *I* have *added* to the base system.

Comment: Related: [How to backup settings and list of installed packages?](/q/9135/175814)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [How to view a list of packages that were manually installed without their dependancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195782/how-to-view-a-list-of-packages-that-were-manually-installed-without-their-depend).

You can list the apt-get command-line commands you have typed since installation of Ubuntu with:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep 'apt-get install '
```