# Where can I download the php55 (or later) deb for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: deb, offline

I'm trying to install php55 (or later) for my lan-server, but I can't seem to find a package that doesn't require internet to install...
(installation fails since I have no internet)

Where is there a reliable​ source for an offline installer??

Comment: You already have it. Apt will happily install packages offline. Use the same sources apt uses for your download...or packages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your offline machine run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 --print-uris -y | grep -o http.*.deb
```

it will print all necessary stuff that are match to your running Ubuntu with all dependencies etc which you need to download. download all them at a machine with Internet connection.

Then move them to your offline machine in this path:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

After all run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

---

If your ubuntu machine sources have never been updated so it will not work for you. then try using an standalone utility like `xampp`:

```
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
```

Both php5 and php7 are available for Linux.

Comment: oh looks like http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.12_amd64.deb is no longer available... there is 4.21 however, should I chance that and symlink it as 4.12 or just use the xampp method??

Comment: seems your sources are out of date, we can change `sources.list` in a running machine with an Internet connection to get working links however that might not work for you cause your system is not up to date, I would go with xampp, as I remember it comes with a lot of other utilities too.

Comment: yeah, it's not working anyways... I tried creating symlinks and it still tries to download.

Comment: xampp worked, big thanks for all the help :) now to begin the grueling process of cleaning out the old site. XP

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should first download the package and then install it with

```
sudo dpkg --install package.deb
```

If there are multiple packages, e.g. because you need dependencies, you have to install them one by one. The concrete link to your package depends on which exact version you would like to use and whether you have a 32 or 64 bit system. A list of packages that are likely to fit is here: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/

If you run `sudo apt --print-uris install php` on another 14.04, `--print-uris` will show the concrete uris to the packages you need to download and install.

**EDIT**
This could be also helpful for you: [How do I generate a package download list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168352/how-do-i-generate-a-package-download-list)

Answer (score 0):

Visit the official Ubuntu (trusty) [Download Page for php5_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21_all.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/php5/download) webpage, and download the php5_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21_all.deb file. Double-click the file you downloaded to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center, or open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the .deb file you downloaded and install it using this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i php5_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21_all.deb
```